# Is there any plugin that provides a tracker-style UI in Logic Pro X?

Tags: logic-pro

I like the piano roll for midi tracks. But I really miss the musical input style of trackers (like FastTracker): vertical; enter the note and duration rather than positioning a note on a piano role; keyboard driven; multiple tracks visible and editable at once. I feel like it was faster to work with. Are there any plugins that can provide a tracker UI for Logic Pro X?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good question. Trackers have a special workflow and expressive power, "not necessarily realtime, but *practically real time at your own pace*" speed of note entry, mapping directly to a computer keyboard, entering and editing in total undistracted concentration, expressions for completely fluid pitch bends and portamento not available any other way, sound-mangling, musical building blocks. A lot of the things that are done in trackers are practically not doable at all in a MIDI sequencer such as Cubase or Ableton Live. As a compositional tool, trackers have their special place, and for a certain style of working, nothing comes even close. If you haven't used them, you have no idea what I'm talking about. And don't think about making credible "real music" with them, it's going sound like electronic music, and that's the whole point.

This is not really a plugin, but Renoise can be used with ReWire. And Renoise works as its own complete DAW, and you can use VST instrument plugins (though then you'll have to limit your music to the handicap of what MIDI can express to the plugins, meaning that you won't be able to do portamentos like with samples, or 9xx sample offset tricks, if those are your thing)
https://tutorials.renoise.com/wiki/ReWire

And then there's Polyend Tracker, which is a standalone hardware device. No idea how good it is for combining with a computer DAW, but at least it has a MIDI output as well as input. https://polyend.com/

One way that might work is splitting your work between a "tracker phase" and "mixing phase" where you first create the structure and composition in a tracker, and then export that as "stems" to a MIDI+audio DAW of your liking, such as Logic.

If FastTracker II is your thing, there are modern alternatives such as MilkyTracker (https://milkytracker.org/) and the recently published FT2 clone (https://github.com/8bitbubsy/ft2-clone).

If someone complains about "product recommendations", I see these as instruments. You cannot go to a music shop and compare different trackers, you're limited to a few pieces of software which actually get the job done the way you want, and that's it. It's not like there are dozens of actually usable alternatives, each application is so different. If you want to talk about the whole subject at all, you'll very soon have to mention a specific application by name. With guitars you can talk about "a Strat" without saying Fender Stratocaster.